# How to use civitAI checkpoint with ControlNet

Tags: python, stable-diffusion

I am in the early stage of learning `Stable Diffusion`.

**Motivation:**
I would like to generate real object picture from line art like [this](https://web.facebook.com/groups/stablediffusionthailand/permalink/1279268646021590/).

I found that I need to use `ControlNet`. However, when I download `majicMIX realistic`. It does not support `ControlNet` which I can input image to it.

Here is my attempt.

```py
from diffusers import StableDiffusionPipeline, Stable
import torch
torch.manual_seed(111)
device = torch.device("mps") if torch.backends.mps.is_available() else torch.device("cpu")

pipe = StableDiffusionPipeline.from_ckpt("majicmixRealistic_v5.safetensors", load_safety_checker=False).to(device)

prompt = "A photo of rough collie, best quality"

negative_prompt: str = "low quality"
guidance_scale = 1
eta = 0.0
result = pipe(
    prompt, num_inference_steps=30, num_images_per_prompt=8,
    guidance_scale=1, negative_prompt=negative_prompt)
for idx, image in enumerate(result.images):
    image.save(f"character_{guidance_scale}_{eta}_{idx}.png")
```

But I can't use this `model` with `ControlNet`. Because it is `checkpoint`.

Next on I use `StableDiffusionImg2ImgPipeline`. This one I can put `text` and `image` together, but I can't use `ControlNet`.

```py
"""
https://huggingface.co/docs/diffusers/using-diffusers/img2img
"""
import torch
from diffusers import StableDiffusionImg2ImgPipeline
from diffusers.utils import load_image

device = "mps" if torch.backends.mps.is_available() else "cpu"
pipe = StableDiffusionImg2ImgPipeline.from_ckpt("majicmixRealistic_v5.safetensors").to(
    device
)

url = "../try_image_to_image/c.jpeg"
init_image = load_image(url)

prompt = "A woman, realistic color photo, high quality"
generator = torch.Generator(device=device).manual_seed(1024)
strengths = [0.3, 0.35, 0.4, 0.45, 0.5]
guidance_scales = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
num_inference_steps = 100
print(f"Total run: {len(strengths) * len(guidance_scales)}")
for strength in strengths:
    for guidance_scale in guidance_scales:
        # image= pipe(prompt=prompt, image=init_image, strength=0.75, guidance_scale=7.5, generator=generator).images[0]
        image = pipe(
            prompt=prompt, image=init_image, strength=strength, guidance_scale=guidance_scale,
            generator=generator, num_inference_steps=num_inference_steps).images[0]
        image.save(f"images/3rd_{strength}_{guidance_scale}.png")
```

**Question:**
How to use `ContronNet` with `majicmix-realistic`?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @off99555
To summarize my steps

1. Download [safetensors](https://civitai.com/models/43331/majicmix-realistic)
2. Download [python file](https://github.com/huggingface/diffusers/blob/main/scripts/convert_original_stable_diffusion_to_diffusers.py)
3. `mkdir converted`
4. `python convert_original_stable_diffusion_to_diffusers.py --checkpoint_path majicmixRealistic_v5.safetensors --from_safetensors --dump_path converted`
5. ```py
    controlnet = ControlNetModel.from_pretrained("lllyasviel/sd-controlnet-canny").to(device)
    pipe = StableDiffusionControlNetPipeline.from_pretrained(
        "converted",  # This line
        safety_checker=None,
        controlnet=controlnet,
    ).to(device)
   ```

Then I can use `majicmix-realistic` model.

Answer (score 0):

Use `StableDiffusionControlNetPipeline` instead of `StableDiffusionPipeline`.
The ControlNet pipeline requires specification of base model e.g. SD 1.5 and ControlNet model e.g. sd-controlnet-canny.
You can replace base model with majicmix and replace sd-controlnet-canny with whatever you want.

Example code:

```py
from diffusers import StableDiffusionControlNetPipeline, ControlNetModel
import torch

controlnet = ControlNetModel.from_pretrained("lllyasviel/sd-controlnet-canny", torch_dtype=torch.float16)
pipe = StableDiffusionControlNetPipeline.from_pretrained(
    "runwayml/stable-diffusion-v1-5", controlnet=controlnet, torch_dtype=torch.float16
)

out_image = pipe(
    "disco dancer with colorful lights", num_inference_steps=20, image=canny_image
).images[0]
```

Read more here: https://huggingface.co/docs/diffusers/v0.16.0/en/api/pipelines/stable_diffusion/controlnet

Comment: When I use absolute path. It returns `HFValidationError: Repo id must be in the form 'repo_name' or 'namespace/repo_name': '/Users/sarit/study/try_openai/try_civitai/majicmixRealistic_v5.safetensors'. Use `repo_type` argument if needed.`

Comment: When I use only filename since it is in the same directory. The error is `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/sarit/.cache/huggingface/hub/models--majicmixRealistic_v5.safetensors/refs/main'`

Comment: `diffusers` can only read files in their own format which must be a folder. It won't understand the single file format. You need to first convert the single file format into `diffusers` folder format first using this script: https://github.com/huggingface/diffusers/blob/main/scripts/convert_original_stable_diffusion_to_diffusers.py

Or try other models that people already converted for you e.g. https://huggingface.co/sinkinai/majicMIX-realistic-v5